# Cannot access instance metadata from within a FARGATE Task

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I have an AWS FARGATE Task that is running a relatively simple python application (with a Docker image built from python:3.6-stretch .)  It runs fine using Amazon EC2 Tasks (Where an EC2 host provides the docker container); but I'm trying to move these to FARGATE.

When I deploy my images in Fargate and they attempt to get the local IPv4 data using the URL:

'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4'

I get the error:

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='169.254.169.254', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /latest/meta-data/local-ipv4 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f086aa8d438>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 22] Invalid argument',))
```

As a side note, my FARGATE container here is sitting on a private subnet ( there is a nat gateway configured and the instance(s) can get out to the internet) .  the IP space is 10.160.16.0/20 .

The image is based on the python:3.6-stretch docker image.

Is there something I need to do to get a FARGATE task to be able to access the link-local address?

TIA!

Comment: Just as a note - when AWS FARGATE launches a container it sets the AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI variable.  Make sure you propagate that variable to any processes you call (such as if you start cron) because otherwise they won't get the var and won't be able to acquire credentials.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is because you are using the wrong endpoint for AWS Fargate. According to the docs listed below, your IP is wrong.

Use `169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` to get IAM metadata.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html

I hope this helps :)

Comment: My understanding is that the 169.254.170.2/v2/metadata endpoint is for docker container metadata.  I need IAM metadata - which isn't available from the docker metadata.

Comment: @chander that's ec2 metadata, not IAM. Fargate is not ec2.

Comment: Okay.  I stand corrected - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html seems to indicate that "169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI" can be used to retrieve the IAM credentials.

Comment: @shawn-clake - want to update your answer to reference the doc and the right way to get the data and I can mark this as the answer? :-)  I always hate to see an answer that I need to read through the comments to get to the bottom of..

Comment: Thanks.  Just as a note (in case it helps others..)  The end issue I had was that I had a bit of code that depended on Python's old boto library - and not boto3.  Apparently Boto was too old to know how to get credentials ; but boto3 was.  I removed the component that depended on boto and replaced it with a boto3 component.  Viola, things work now..

Comment: @shawn, any way to fetch public-ipv4?

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to answer the original question. In order to fetch the IP address information for the task running on AWS Fargate with Amazon ECS, you can use [Amazon ECS task metadata endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4-fargate.html). The endpoint URI is injected automatically to each container within the task as environment variable `ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4`.

For example:

```
curl ${ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4}
```

will return

```
{
    "DockerId": "cd189a933e5849daa93386466019ab50-2495160603",
    "Name": "curl",
    "DockerName": "curl",
    "Image": "111122223333.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/curltest:latest",
    "ImageID": "sha256:25f3695bedfb454a50f12d127839a68ad3caf91e451c1da073db34c542c4d2cb",
    "Labels": {
        "com.amazonaws.ecs.cluster": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:111122223333:cluster/default",
        "com.amazonaws.ecs.container-name": "curl",
        "com.amazonaws.ecs.task-arn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:111122223333:task/default/cd189a933e5849daa93386466019ab50",
        "com.amazonaws.ecs.task-definition-family": "curltest",
        "com.amazonaws.ecs.task-definition-version": "2"
    },
    "DesiredStatus": "RUNNING",
    "KnownStatus": "RUNNING",
    "Limits": {
        "CPU": 10,
        "Memory": 128
    },
    "CreatedAt": "2020-10-08T20:09:11.44527186Z",
    "StartedAt": "2020-10-08T20:09:11.44527186Z",
    "Type": "NORMAL",
    "Networks": [
        {
            "NetworkMode": "awsvpc",
            "IPv4Addresses": [
                "192.0.2.3"
            ],
            "AttachmentIndex": 0,
            "MACAddress": "0a:de:f6:10:51:e5",
            "IPv4SubnetCIDRBlock": "192.0.2.0/24",
            "DomainNameServers": [
                "192.0.2.2"
            ],
            "DomainNameSearchList": [
                "us-west-2.compute.internal"
            ],
            "PrivateDNSName": "ip-10-0-0-222.us-west-2.compute.internal",
            "SubnetGatewayIpv4Address": "192.0.2.0/24"
        }
    ],
    "ContainerARN": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:111122223333:container/05966557-f16c-49cb-9352-24b3a0dcd0e1",
    "LogOptions": {
        "awslogs-create-group": "true",
        "awslogs-group": "/ecs/containerlogs",
        "awslogs-region": "us-west-2",
        "awslogs-stream": "ecs/curl/cd189a933e5849daa93386466019ab50"
    },
    "LogDriver": "awslogs"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is python version of the process to get role credentials from within the Fargate container. Although the code below is for a S3 bucket (tested Dec 2020), the principle applies for other AWS services as well. Just initiate your boto3 client for that service and attach correct role to the Fargate task with the right policy. The relative credential URI looks similar to '/v2/credentials/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx' (mind the forward slash at the beginning) if you're interested.

```
creds_uri = os.environ.get('AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI')
r = requests.get('http://169.254.170.2{}'.format(creds_uri))
credentials = r.json()
s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                         aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
                         aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
                         aws_session_token=credentials['Token'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get data from environment variable. Don't use IP address directly.

In my situation my environment variable has some random string appended to IP address. So better to call get request on environment variable: `ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4`